# When changing file names in an array ToLower(), do I need to repopulate the array after changing file names to lower?

Tags: c#, arrays, path

```
if (fbFolderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                LastSelectedFolder = fbFolderBrowser.SelectedPath;

                originalFiles = Directory.GetFiles(fbFolderBrowser.SelectedPath).Where(file => !file.EndsWith(".db")).ToArray();

                //lower casing the extensions here.
                foreach (string file in originalFiles)
                {
                    File.Move(file, Path.ChangeExtension(file, Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower()));
                }

                //after im done changing the files to lower case, do I need to repopulate the array with the lowered case file names?
                originalFiles = Directory.GetFiles(fbFolderBrowser.SelectedPath).Where(file => !file.EndsWith(".db")).ToArray();
            }
```

After I go through each file in a folder and make sure the extension is lower case, do I need to repopulate the array (in this case originalFiles) with the lowered case names like I'm doing above?

Comment: You can better use a string comparison ignoring case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the appropriate overload of [`EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131430.aspx) and you can stop caring about case.

```
// for example
file.EndsWith(".db", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: ahhh, I didn't know there was a function to ignore case. I guess this will do. thanks! ps. need 8 mins to accept your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The file extensions that are generated by `GetExtension`() method is case sensitive in .Net

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "will original string object be changed here":

```
File.Move(file, Path.ChangeExtension(file, Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower()));
```

then the answer is "no", each item in `originalFiles` array will remain unchanged.